# Prestashop custom module variable passed to Theme .tpl file

Tags: php, prestashop

Im trying to pass my own variable from module to template file .tpl

I have this code that is used for displaying availability in eshop. **Product.tpl**

```
                            {if $product.availability == 'available'}
                                {if $product.quantity <= 0  && $product.allow_oosp}
                                    {if isset($product.available_date) && $product.available_date != '0000-00-00'}
                                        <i class="fa fa-truck rtl-no-flip" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        {$product.availability_message} 
                                        ({if $product.available_date|strtotime > $smarty.now}<span class="available-date">{l s='naskladnění' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'} {$product.available_date|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y"}</span>{/if})
                                    {/if}
{/if}{/if}
```

Then Im having my own module where im assigning value to smarty
**Mymodule.php**

```
    $in_stock = 1;
    $this->context->smarty->assign("is_in_stock", $in_stock);
```

My question is if there is any way to **access my smarty variable directly from theme tpl**? I need to set up another {if else} with that variable but cant access it.

When I add variable to custom hook I cant access it neither.. Or maybe I dont know how. I tried to **create front controller** but nothing happened.

Something like

```
{if isset($product.available_date) && $mymodule.is_in_stock = 1 && $product.available_date != '0000-00-00'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access functions of your module anywhere in .tpl files by

{YourModule::yourFunction()}

and set if like

{if YourModule::yourFunction() != 1}
Hello
{/if}